# Will the implementation of mremap free physical pages?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

Recently, I am reading the memory management part of linux kernel code (the version I am reading is 4.10). I find that the implementation of mremap is strange.

In short, `sys_mremap()` will call `move_vma()`, which basically will do the following:

1. `copy_vma()`
2. `move_page_tables()`
3. `do_munmap()`

The step 1 and 2 are easy to understand, they just copy from the old memory mapping into the new mapping. However, they do not increment the refcount of struct page while copying to new memory mapping in these two steps (I do not find it in source code).

Then in step 3, kernel will unmap the old mappings. It iterates every vma and every pages, decrement the refcount of struct page and finally call `tlb_flush_mmu_free()` to free all pages.

My question is:

1. if the kernel implement mremap like this, the following access to the pages will cause page fault?
2. why kernel does not increment the refcount when `move_vma()`? It will keep pages in memory after mremap and will not casue the unnecessary page fault.
3. what about anonymous and private mapped pages? How can user access the content after this kind of pages has been freed?